# Angular: Use $rootScope in Interceptor

Tags: angularjs

I have a controller:

```
 app.controller('MyController', function ($scope, $http, $rootScope, AuctionService) {

    $scope.setToken = function (code) {
        $rootScope.access_token = code;
    };
    AuctionService.auctions();
});
```

I set the `access_token` in `$rootScope` and want to use it in an interceptor:

```
app.factory('httpRequestInterceptor', ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
    return {
        request: function ($config) {
            $config.headers = {'Authentication': 'Bearer ' + $rootScope.access_token};
            return $config;
        }
    };
}]);
```

But my `access_token` is always undefined.  As far as I know, it should work like this. If you have any other suggestion how use the `access_token` in an Interceptor would be fine as well.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that the interceptor is created before you create an access token is assigned. Root scope is not a good place for a token either, the best way is to wrap it into a special service and use that to extract it, e.g. tokenService.getToken(), then you can remember the token on the first access or read it every time from storage or something like that.

An issue that you might encounter doing that is a circular reference in the interceptor, in that case you can inject the service yourself using the $inject instead of using constructor injection, or use some other technique to overcome it.

Comment: yes, this is the right path. to learn more about loading dependencies like this, take a quick peek at the docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module#module-loading-dependencies

Answer (score 0):

I think you not define $rootScope variable in run method. like

```
app.run(function($rootScope){
    $rootScope.access_token = null;
});
```